# "Segmentation fault" when `rmmod` or `modprobe -r`

Tags: c, linux, kernel, embedded, kernel-module

Trying the simplest kernel module from [LDD3](https://lwn.net/Kernel/LDD3/) without any modification on custom built kernel v4.1.0-rc6 for Beagle Bone board with BusyBox v1.23.0. The code for the module is as follows:

```
#include <linux/init.h>
#include <linux/module.h>
MODULE_LICENSE("Dual BSD/GPL");
static int hello_init(void)
{
    printk(KERN_ALERT "Hello, world\n");
    return 0;
}
static void hello_exit(void)
{
    printk(KERN_ALERT "Goodbye, cruel world\n");
}
module_init(hello_init);
module_exit(hello_exit);
```

The Makefile is:

```
ARCH := arm
CROSS_COMPILE := arm-cortex_a8-linux-gnueabi-
obj-m := hello.o
all:
        make ARCH=$(ARCH) CROSS_COMPILE=$(CROSS_COMPILE) -C /path/to/linux/source/tree M=$(PWD) modules
clean:
        make ARCH=$(ARCH) CROSS_COMPILE=$(CROSS_COMPILE) -C /path/to/linux/source/tree M=$(PWD) clean
```

The module is compiling and installing on the rootfs just fine. also it is loading:

```
$ insmod hello.ko 
[   30.692404] Hello, world
```

But when trying to remove it, I am getting:

```
$ rmmod hello.ko 
Segmentation fault
$modprobe -r hello.ko 
Segmentation fault
$ lsmod
hello 813 0 - Live 0xbf000000 (O)
```

The kernel is compiled with module unloading (both regular and forced) support enabled.

What can be the possible cause of this issue? What is the way to approach the investigation of it?

**Update:**

As suggested in the comments I have tried including `linux/kernel.h`, defining the `MODULE`,`LINUX` and `__KERNEL__` symbols. Added the`__init` and `__exit` prefixes to the functions. Removed the `static` modifiers. Removed the `printk` lines. The result the same. `dmesg` shows only the initial greeting. Loading and unloading of the kernel's modules such a `gpio_keys` or `crypto/ccm` **is** working, surprisingly. So the only thing remaining to suspect is the way the module is compiled..

**Update 2**
Updating the kernel to the freshest snapshot didn't help. Compiled the module with different optimization settings didn't help. Next step, I guess, I am going to modify the BusyBox's rmmod to have some indication of the problem location..

Comment: The code looks fine. Do you see anymore info in /var/log/messages (or dmesg) when removing it? Does it happen with your module only and can you load/unload any system modules successfully?

Comment: @BlueMoon Unfortunately, I don't even have the `/var` directory right now on my rootfs :) I am building it from scratch, and I am not sure which additional service should be installed in order to write the messages.. Maybe I should start by doing so.

Comment: Can you load/unload others, for example `modprobe nfs` and `modprobe -r nfs` successfully? `dmesg` says anything useful?

Comment: @Blue Moon I will take a look at these later today, have to go to work now. I know the modules are loading. Not sure about unloading. Is `dmesg` available on bare bones system with busybox only? Anyway, thanks for the direction.

Comment: Just run `dmesg` on the commandline to find out.

Comment: I will once back to my lab. Thanks

Comment: for grins, add #include <linux/kernel.h>

Comment: @BlueMoon Please see the update. It is really weird.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to work around this problem. Using `strace` I've found out that the segfault is occurring somewhere when `read`ing the `BusyBox` specific `modules.dep.bb` file. This file is used by `BusyBox` when it is compiled with the "Simplified modutils" option (`CONFIG_MODPROBE_SMALL`). By disabling the option, selecting the utils to be installed and rebuilding BusybBox I've got the module unloading work. I believe the problem root is near the fact the test module is compiled and stored outside the `/lib/..../modules` directory, so `busybox` with the simplified `modutils` is just getting confused.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at these tutorials:

http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Module-HOWTO/x839.html
http://www.tldp.org/LDP/lkmpg/2.4/html/x281.htm

Try adding:

```
#define MODULE
#define LINUX
#define __KERNEL__

#include <linux/kernel.h>      /* Needed for KERN_ALERT */
```